# Silverlight Toolkit v5.0 Menu, SL4PopupMenu

Tags: silverlight-4.0, menu, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

Which menu have you used with Silverlight 4 and Silverlight Toolkit 5? Is there a free menu that can be used with this Silverlight version combination?
I tried to use SL4PopupMenu, but get the exception

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit, Version=4.0.5.0,
```

or

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls, Version=5.0.5.0,
```

when I change the reverence version of `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit` from 4 to 5.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Why would you use the SL5 version of the Toolkit with SL4?

Comment: I don't know. This is a good question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you recompile the source code for the menu after updating the SL4 references in the project to SL5. This should get rid of the exception.